# Jenkins Job DSL Plugin - Script Execution Order

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

When specifying multiple lines of script wildcards to execute (in the *DSL Scripts* field), does the plugin make any guarantees about the execution order of the scripts? As of release **job-dsl-1.43**, the execution order has changed (apparently as a result of the fix for **JENKINS-30541**). Now, scripts execute in the order that they appear in the *DSL Scripts* field. I can't rely on this ordering when creating DSL jobs because it's based on knowing the implementation  (the *.each* closure together with the *LinkedHashSet* that stores the script request).
I would like to be able to depend on the execution order.
Is it possible to add documentation that will guarantee that scripts will be run in the same order as they appear?

Comment: Thanks! Your change solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are executed in the same order as specified in the *DSL Scripts* field. The execution order of expanded wildcards is unspecified.

See [JENKINS-33081](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33081) and [PR #789](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/789).